# How to instantiate an Optional in python?

Tags: python, python-typing

I'm trying to define a function which should return `Optional[Foo]` if a condition matches - but `None` if it doesn't match.

But, I can't figure out how to instantiate an optional:

```
def find_user(self, id: str) -> Optional[User]:
    try:
        user = User.foo.find(id = id)
        return Optional(user])

    except:
        return None
```

However this doesn't seem to be matching the expected type in my IDE. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try just `return user`? Does `User.foo.find` actually return a `User` instance?

Comment: Also, what happened when you read the documentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Optional isn't a type you can instantiate. It's just a shorthand for `Union[User, None]`. So you would just `return user`.

It's not a standalone type like you might know from Haskell, Swift, Rust, Kotlin, or Java, etc. So you can't call `map` on it, or treat it in anyway distinct from a regular `User` or `None`.

Comment: If I just `return user`, my IDE reads the return type as `Coroutine[Any,Any,Model]` instead of `Optional[User]`. But it accepts `return Optional[user]` - is that also accurate?

Comment: @ClickUpvote: That sounds like you're misunderstanding what `User.foo.find` actually returns - it doesn't sound like it returns a User.

Comment: Right, here's the actual method: https://collerek.github.io/ormar/queries/filter-and-sort/#get . My `User` model inherits from the `Model` instance of this library

Comment: @ClickUpvote: The documentation for that library confusingly fails to mention which things are coroutines and which are non-async. You're probably trying to treat a coroutine like a synchronous call.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica  Looks like you need to brush up on async/await/yield

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Right, that library is all async. I tried making my function `async` and added an `await` on the call, but still getting the warning in IDE.

Comment: @Alexander: I'm not sure why you're saying that to me. Are you trying to say the documentation *isn't* confusing? The `get` docs have no "this is a coroutine" indicator, and the examples include lines like `track = Track.objects.filter(name="The Bird").get()`, where the method is used as if it's not a coroutine.

Comment: Ok, I guess the issue is that the library returns `Model` instead of User. I'll accept the answer since it explains what the question asked :)

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I tagged the wrong person :) I meant to tag the OP, "Click Upvote"